# Are disappearing objects in a video game the garbage collector

Tags: video, game-engine

For example if you kill an enemy in a game and it's body dissappear is it the garbage collector deleting the object clearing up ram for the console and Pc are more powerful than consoles so do games on a Pc need a garbage collector or do I have the whole concept wrong.

Comment: This depends on how the specific game engine is coded but most likely they are explicitly deleted in the code. Please note Stack Overflow is a Q+A site for specific programming questions so this question could be deemed off topic.

Comment: This shouldn't be on stack overflow. Rather the gaming section of stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the whole concept wrong.  Specifically, you are confusing application logic -- in this case, an implemented function that is part of a game's design -- with under-the-hood and automatic memory management.

A "garbage collector" is part of an automatic memory management system that frees programmers from having to keep track of and manually delete objects from memory in order to use it again.  This is one reason (among many) that higher level languages that feature automatic garbage collection -- like Java -- are easier to program with than lower level languages that make you do it all yourself, like C or Assembly.

It is possible that any given game may use a garbage collector somewhere in its engine.  It is also possible that the game's designers and programmers may have implemented a "clean up the map" routine, either as part of the game design or as a memory management measure (in which case it is a very high-level manual memory management, which is actually the opposite of garbage collection).

But the answer to your question is no: to refer to items disappearing from a game -- even if they disappear to save memory -- as a garbage collector is a juxtaposition of concepts and is completely incorrect.